# How to compare property in using MongoDB Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I translate `db.monthlyBudget.find( { $expr: { $gt: [ "$spent" , "$budget" ] } } )`
into C# using the MongoDB Driver.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
new BsonDocumentFilterDefine<T>(new BsonDocument("$expr"," $gt: [ \"$spent\" , \"$budget\" ]"))
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**MongoDB.Driver**:

```cs
    var res = collection.Find("{$expr:{$gt:['$Spent','$Budget']}}")
                        .ToList();
```

**MongoDB.Entities**:

```cs
using MongoDB.Entities;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Project : Entity
        {
            public decimal Budget { get; set; }
            public decimal Spent { get; set; }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test", "localhost");

            (new Project
            {
                Budget = 10000,
                Spent = 11000
            }).Save();

            var res = DB.Find<Project>()
                        .MatchExpression("{$gt:['$Spent','$Budget']}")
                        .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```